Split integral over product $(x,y)\in E_1\times E_2$ into integral over image $e\in f(E_1,E_2)$ and fiber $(x,y)\in f^{-1}(e)$.
Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, and let $f : X\times X\to X$ be continuous. For sets $E_1, E_2\subseteq X$, define $f(E_1, E_2) = \{f(e_1, e_2)\mid e_i\in E_i\}$, and $f^{-1}(e) = \{(a,b)\in X^2\mid f(a,b) = e\}$.
I want to know if for any "nice" (essentially any condition is fine, concretely one can say "continuous") function $g: X\times X\to X$, one has that
$$
\int_{(x,y)\in E_1\times E_2}g(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{e\in f(E_1, E_2)}\int_{(x,y)\in f^{-1}(e)}g(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}e,
$$
or something approximately like this (perhaps with some $e$-depending scaling factors on the right).
What I essentially want is that one can breakup the integral over $E_1\times E_2$ into an integral over the image $\{e\in f(E_1,E_2)\}$, and the fiber $f^{-1}(e)$.
I'm only interested in the above for "very nice" $f$, namely $f\in\{+,\times\}$.
I'm also interested in an $n$-dimensional generalization (though the $n$-dimensional variant of $\times$ is somewhat annoying to define --- it is multiplication in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n+1)$.
